# Raycast - convert from C# to UnityScript

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I was following a tutorial for Unity3D that was written in C# and was attempting to do it in UnityScript.  The following line is the only one that I couldn't convert correctly and it has to do with Raycasting.

Here's the C# from the tut.

```
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Abs(deltaY), collisionMask)){
    ....
}
```

Here are my relevant variables that I have.

```
var ray : Ray;
var hit : RaycastHit;
var collisionMask : LayerMask;
var deltaY : float = moveAmount.y; // moveAmount is a Vector2
```

Here is the signature for Physics.Raycast

```
function Raycast (origin : Vector3,
                  direction : Vector3,
                  distance : float = Mathf.Infinity,
                  layerMask : int = kDefaultRaycastLayers) : boolean
```

I know that my problem is that using UnityScript doesn't recognize what 'out' is and I don't know what to substitute in its place.

Comment: How are you calling it in `UnityScript`?

Comment: I read that some people don't like to call it Javascript because Unity can change the documentation for it as they please so it doesn't strictly follow all Javascript rules.

Comment: It's true that it is only JavaScript-esque. Unity has a custom JavaScript engine that allows them to modify the normal syntax of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html):

```
static function Raycast(ray: Ray,
                        hitInfo: RaycastHit,
                        distance: float = Mathf.Infinity,
                        layerMask: int = DefaultRaycastLayers): bool;
```

Parameters (read the description for hitInfo)

```
ray          The starting point and direction of the ray.
distance     The length of the ray.
hitInfo      If true is returned, hitInfo will contain more information about where the 
             collider was hit (See Also: RaycastHit).
layerMask    A Layer mask that is used to selectively ignore colliders when casting a ray.
```

In C#, `out` passes by reference, which allows the function to modify the value outside its scope. In `UnityScript`, you don't need to define when to pass by reference or value. So, you simply omit the `out`.

```
var ray : Ray;
var hit : RaycastHit;
var collisionMask : LayerMask;
var deltaY : float = moveAmount.y; // moveAmount is a Vector2

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit, deltaY, collisionMask)) {
    //hit will contain more information about whether the collider was a hit here.
}
```

Notice, according to the [**`LayerMask` documentation**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html), `LayerMask` can be implicitly converted from an integer.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that the RaycastHit being passed in was being modified.  I thought I had to give it a direction.

Comment: @Andrew_CS The `Ray` should have all of the direction information I believe. Glad this helped.

Answer (score 2):

out means that the parameter passed to it will be passed "by reference", as opposed to "by value". [See C# documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx).

I'm not familiar with UnityScript. But one way to create an equivalent function would be to create a new class to be returned that contains the Boolean that would normally be returned, as well as the RaycastHit object.

```
class MyCustomReturnObject
    Boolean OriginalReturnVariable
    RaycastHit hit
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need the out keyword at all.

```
var hit : RaycastHit;
if (Physics.Raycast (origin, direction, hit, distance)) {
    var hitDistance = hit.distance;
}
```

You can use the UnityScript docs for reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

`out` and `ref` keywords are useful C# constructs that allow you to pass a reference to a structure (or a reference to a class reference), which would usually be passed by value instead.

The C# variant of the method would create a new instance of the RaycastHit type and assign it to the variable you pass as an `out` parameter.

In UnityScript, this is unnecessary, and you'll get what you expect without using the `out` keyword.